# How can I fix "SystemError: null argument to internal routine" error when python callback in called from C

Tags: python, c, gdb, swig

## Intro

I'm writing a python application which uses a library written in C.
When some event occurred at C level a Python callback is used to be called.

Here is a part of my python callback definition:

```
def callback(str1, str2, cdata, flag):
  print("PYTHON HANDLER")
  ...
  print(">>EXIT<<")
```

Before passing **callback** to C it is converted using this code:

```
FuncType = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p,
                            ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_bool)

ctype_function_wrapper = FuncType(callback)
cfunction_pointer = ctypes.cast(ctype_function_wrapper, ctypes.c_void_p)
py_callback_ptr = cfunction_pointer.value
```

After that **py_callback_ptr** is passed to C library and saved there as a (void *) pointer.

When an event occurs C level **py_callback_ptr** is called. Here is a piece of code which does this at C level:

```
...
printf("Acquire GIL\r\n");
PyGILState_STATE gstate;
gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
printf("Callback()\r\n");
((void (*)(char*, char*, DataStructure*, bool))py_callback_ptr)(
    str1, str2, value, bool_flag);
printf("Callback return\r\n");
PyGILState_Release(gstate);
printf("Release GIL\r\n");
...
```

Most of the time it works as expected and callback is called. I get this output in stdout:

```
...
Acquire GIL
Callback()
PYTHON HANDLER
>>EXIT<<
Callback return
Release GIL
...
```

But some times I get this output mixed with stderr output. It shows me that C code around callback executed normally but callback itself didn't executed:

```
...
Acquire GIL
Callback()
SystemError: null argument to internal routine      # from stderr
Callback return
Release GIL
...
```

## Research

I have looked for SystemError in Python and [found the explanation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemError)

> Raised when the interpreter finds an internal error, but the situation does not look so serious to cause it to abandon all hope. The associated value is a string indicating what went wrong (in low-level terms).

So this is error caught in interpreter code which writes to stderr some string. I decided to catch that call and investigate it.

## Debugging

I have tried to catch this error in gdb.
I have set up a breakpoint which stops program execution on stderr output using this command:

```
(gdb) b write if 2==$rdi
```

Also a have caught backtrace of normal callback execution. Here they are.

Part of normal backtrace:

```
#0  write () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#1  0x0000000000437735 in _Py_write_impl (gil_held=1, count=4, buf=<optimized out>, fd=2) at Python/fileutils.c:1331
#2  _Py_write (fd=2, buf=0x961100, count=<optimized out>) at Python/fileutils.c:1393
#3  0x00000000005b73ce in _io_FileIO_write_impl (b=0x7ffff3916b00, b=0x7ffff3916b00, self=0x7ffff7f0c3a8) at ./Modules/_io/fileio.c:857
#4  _io_FileIO_write (self=0x7ffff7f0c3a8, arg=<optimized out>) at ./Modules/_io/clinic/fileio.c.h:251
#5  0x00000000004aa139 in _PyCFunction_FastCallDict (func_obj=func_obj@entry=0x7ffff4f9d828, args=args@entry=0x7ffff3916c40, nargs=nargs@entry=1, kwargs=kwargs@entry=0x0) at Objects/methodobject.c:209
#6  0x0000000000451b68 in _PyObject_FastCallDict (func=0x7ffff4f9d828, args=0x7ffff3916c40, nargs=1, kwargs=0x0) at Objects/abstract.c:2313
#7  0x0000000000452b86 in PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs (callable=0x7ffff4f9d828, name=<optimized out>) at Objects/abstract.c:2759
#8  0x00000000005bb24a in _bufferedwriter_raw_write (self=self@entry=0x7ffff7fd0b48, start=<optimized out>, len=4) at ./Modules/_io/bufferedio.c:1853
#9  0x00000000005bbd0f in _bufferedwriter_flush_unlocked (self=self@entry=0x7ffff7fd0b48) at ./Modules/_io/bufferedio.c:1898
#10 buffered_flush_and_rewind_unlocked (self=self@entry=0x7ffff7fd0b48) at ./Modules/_io/bufferedio.c:827
#11 0x00000000005bbf27 in buffered_flush (self=0x7ffff7fd0b48, args=<optimized out>) at ./Modules/_io/bufferedio.c:854
#12 0x00000000004aa1ff in _PyCFunction_FastCallDict (func_obj=func_obj@entry=0x7ffff4f9d5a0, args=args@entry=0x7ffff3916f30, nargs=nargs@entry=0, kwargs=kwargs@entry=0x0) at Objects/methodobject.c:192
#13 0x0000000000451b68 in _PyObject_FastCallDict (func=0x7ffff4f9d5a0, args=0x7ffff3916f30, nargs=0, kwargs=0x0) at Objects/abstract.c:2313
#14 0x0000000000452b86 in PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs (callable=0x7ffff4f9d5a0, name=<optimized out>) at Objects/abstract.c:2759
#15 0x00000000005c1924 in _io_TextIOWrapper_write_impl (text=0x7ffff7f30a40, self=0x7ffff7f7d708) at ./Modules/_io/textio.c:1367
#16 _io_TextIOWrapper_write (self=0x7ffff7f7d708, arg=<optimized out>) at ./Modules/_io/clinic/textio.c.h:216
#17 0x00000000004aa139 in _PyCFunction_FastCallDict (func_obj=func_obj@entry=0x7ffff4f9d5e8, args=args@entry=0x7ffff3917148, nargs=nargs@entry=1, kwargs=kwargs@entry=0x0) at Objects/methodobject.c:209
#18 0x0000000000451b68 in _PyObject_FastCallDict (func=func@entry=0x7ffff4f9d5e8, args=args@entry=0x7ffff3917148, nargs=nargs@entry=1, kwargs=kwargs@entry=0x0) at Objects/abstract.c:2313
#19 0x000000000047a4cc in PyFile_WriteObject (flags=1, f=<optimized out>, v=0x7ffff7f30a40) at Objects/fileobject.c:150
#20 PyFile_WriteString (s=s@entry=0x5e4ac5 "\n", f=<optimized out>) at Objects/fileobject.c:174
#21 0x000000000053b103 in builtin_print (self=<optimized out>, args=0x7ffff65df748, kwds=<optimized out>) at Python/bltinmodule.c:1814
#22 0x00000000004aa3d9 in PyCFunction_Call (func=func@entry=0x7ffff7fcdf30, args=args@entry=0x7ffff65df748, kwds=kwds@entry=0x7ffff4f9d8b8) at Objects/methodobject.c:98
#23 0x0000000000548572 in do_call_core (kwdict=0x7ffff4f9d8b8, callargs=0x7ffff65df748, func=0x7ffff7fcdf30) at Python/ceval.c:5116
#24 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3404
#25 0x000000000053f401 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (throwflag=0, f=0x7ffff4fa1048) at Python/ceval.c:754
#26 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName (_co=0x7ffff7f089c0, globals=globals@entry=0x7ffff7f4c360, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=<optimized out>, argcount=1, kwnames=0x0, kwargs=kwargs@entry=0x7ffff7ed4d60, kwcount=0, kwstep=kwstep@entry=1, 
    defs=0x0, defcount=defcount@entry=0, kwdefs=0x0, closure=0x0, name=name@entry=0x7ffff7f0f3b0, qualname=0x7ffff7f0f3b0) at Python/ceval.c:4166
#27 0x000000000053f6ff in fast_function (kwnames=0x0, nargs=<optimized out>, stack=<optimized out>, func=0x7ffff7f36e18) at Python/ceval.c:4992
#28 call_function (pp_stack=pp_stack@entry=0x7ffff3917550, oparg=<optimized out>, kwnames=kwnames@entry=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:4872
#29 0x000000000054138b in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3335
#30 0x000000000053e791 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (throwflag=0, f=0x7ffff7ed4bb8) at Python/ceval.c:754
#31 _PyFunction_FastCall (co=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, nargs=4, globals=globals@entry=0x7ffff7f4c360) at Python/ceval.c:4933
#32 0x000000000053f927 in fast_function (kwnames=0x0, nargs=<optimized out>, stack=<optimized out>, func=0x7ffff4f9ed08) at Python/ceval.c:4968
#33 call_function (pp_stack=pp_stack@entry=0x7ffff3917770, oparg=<optimized out>, kwnames=kwnames@entry=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:4872
#34 0x000000000054138b in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3335
#35 0x000000000053f401 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (throwflag=0, f=0x7ffff4fa0048) at Python/ceval.c:754
#36 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName (_co=0x7ffff65d0810, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=args@entry=0x7ffff6569330, argcount=4, kwnames=kwnames@entry=0x0, kwargs=kwargs@entry=0x0, kwcount=kwcount@entry=0, 
    kwstep=kwstep@entry=2, defs=defs@entry=0x0, defcount=defcount@entry=0, kwdefs=kwdefs@entry=0x0, closure=closure@entry=0x7ffff7e9e208, name=name@entry=0x0, qualname=qualname@entry=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:4166
#37 0x00000000005401dd in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (_co=<optimized out>, globals=<optimized out>, locals=locals@entry=0x0, args=args@entry=0x7ffff6569330, argcount=<optimized out>, kws=kws@entry=0x0, kwcount=kwcount@entry=0, 
    defs=defs@entry=0x0, defcount=defcount@entry=0, kwdefs=0x0, closure=0x7ffff7e9e208) at Python/ceval.c:4187
#38 0x000000000048101c in function_call (func=0x7ffff4f9eea0, arg=0x7ffff6569318, kw=0x0) at Objects/funcobject.c:604
#39 0x0000000000451820 in PyObject_Call (func=0x7ffff4f9eea0, args=args@entry=0x7ffff6569318, kwargs=<optimized out>) at Objects/abstract.c:2261
#40 0x0000000000540696 in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords (func=func@entry=0x7ffff4f9eea0, args=args@entry=0x7ffff6569318, kwargs=kwargs@entry=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:4771
#41 0x00000000004516e7 in PyObject_CallObject (o=o@entry=0x7ffff4f9eea0, a=a@entry=0x7ffff6569318) at Objects/abstract.c:2187
#42 0x00007ffff4d54d2c in _CallPythonObject (pArgs=<optimized out>, flags=257, converters=0x7ffff656a908, callable=0x7ffff4f9eea0, setfunc=0x0, restype=0x7ffff4f631d0 <ffi_type_void>, mem=0x7ffff3917c20)
    at /home/ns-sergeev/.pythons/src/Python-3.6.8/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.c:234
#43 closure_fcn (cif=<optimized out>, resp=0x7ffff3917c20, args=0x7ffff3917a80, userdata=<optimized out>) at /home/ns-sergeev/.pythons/src/Python-3.6.8/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.c:296
#44 0x00007ffff4b42a6b in ffi_closure_unix64_inner (closure=0x7ffff7ff2010, rvalue=0x7ffff3917c20, reg_args=0x7ffff3917b70, argp=0x7ffff3917c40 "P\r") at ../src/x86/ffi64.c:667
#45 0x00007ffff4b42de4 in ffi_closure_unix64 () at ../src/x86/unix64.S:229
...
C-library frames are omitted
```

Backtrace with callback call error:

```
#0  write () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#1  0x0000000000437735 in _Py_write_impl (gil_held=1, count=47, buf=<optimized out>, fd=2) at Python/fileutils.c:1331
#2  _Py_write (fd=2, buf=0x961100, count=<optimized out>) at Python/fileutils.c:1393
#3  0x00000000005b73ce in _io_FileIO_write_impl (b=0x7ffff3916e80, b=0x7ffff3916e80, self=0x7ffff7f0c3a8) at ./Modules/_io/fileio.c:857
#4  _io_FileIO_write (self=0x7ffff7f0c3a8, arg=<optimized out>) at ./Modules/_io/clinic/fileio.c.h:251
#5  0x00000000004aa139 in _PyCFunction_FastCallDict (func_obj=func_obj@entry=0x7ffff4f9e7e0, args=args@entry=0x7ffff3916fc0, nargs=nargs@entry=1, 
    kwargs=kwargs@entry=0x0) at Objects/methodobject.c:209
#6  0x0000000000451b68 in _PyObject_FastCallDict (func=0x7ffff4f9e7e0, args=0x7ffff3916fc0, nargs=1, kwargs=0x0) at Objects/abstract.c:2313
#7  0x0000000000452b86 in PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs (callable=0x7ffff4f9e7e0, name=<optimized out>) at Objects/abstract.c:2759
#8  0x00000000005bb24a in _bufferedwriter_raw_write (self=self@entry=0x7ffff7fd0b48, start=<optimized out>, len=47) at ./Modules/_io/bufferedio.c:1853
#9  0x00000000005bbd0f in _bufferedwriter_flush_unlocked (self=self@entry=0x7ffff7fd0b48) at ./Modules/_io/bufferedio.c:1898
#10 buffered_flush_and_rewind_unlocked (self=self@entry=0x7ffff7fd0b48) at ./Modules/_io/bufferedio.c:827
#11 0x00000000005bbf27 in buffered_flush (self=0x7ffff7fd0b48, args=<optimized out>) at ./Modules/_io/bufferedio.c:854
#12 0x00000000004aa1ff in _PyCFunction_FastCallDict (func_obj=func_obj@entry=0x7ffff4f9e558, args=args@entry=0x7ffff39172b0, nargs=nargs@entry=0, 
    kwargs=kwargs@entry=0x0) at Objects/methodobject.c:192
#13 0x0000000000451b68 in _PyObject_FastCallDict (func=0x7ffff4f9e558, args=0x7ffff39172b0, nargs=0, kwargs=0x0) at Objects/abstract.c:2313
#14 0x0000000000452b86 in PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs (callable=0x7ffff4f9e558, name=<optimized out>) at Objects/abstract.c:2759
#15 0x00000000005c1924 in _io_TextIOWrapper_write_impl (text=0x7ffff7f30a40, self=0x7ffff7f7d708) at ./Modules/_io/textio.c:1367
#16 _io_TextIOWrapper_write (self=0x7ffff7f7d708, arg=<optimized out>) at ./Modules/_io/clinic/textio.c.h:216
#17 0x00000000004aa139 in _PyCFunction_FastCallDict (func_obj=func_obj@entry=0x7ffff4f9e5a0, args=args@entry=0x7ffff39174c8, nargs=nargs@entry=1, 
    kwargs=kwargs@entry=0x0) at Objects/methodobject.c:209
#18 0x0000000000451b68 in _PyObject_FastCallDict (func=func@entry=0x7ffff4f9e5a0, args=args@entry=0x7ffff39174c8, nargs=nargs@entry=1, 
    kwargs=kwargs@entry=0x0) at Objects/abstract.c:2313
#19 0x000000000047a4cc in PyFile_WriteObject (flags=1, f=0x7ffff7f30a40, v=0x7ffff7f30a40) at Objects/fileobject.c:150
#20 PyFile_WriteString (s=s@entry=0x5e4ac5 "\n", f=f@entry=0x7ffff7f7d708) at Objects/fileobject.c:174
#21 0x0000000000425790 in print_exception (value=<optimized out>, f=0x7ffff7f7d708) at Python/pythonrun.c:819
#22 print_exception_recursive (f=f@entry=0x7ffff7f7d708, value=value@entry=0x7ffff4f9a1a8, seen=seen@entry=0x7ffff650ee48) at Python/pythonrun.c:891
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#23 0x0000000000426683 in PyErr_Display (exception=<optimized out>, value=0x7ffff4f9a1a8, tb=<optimized out>) at Python/pythonrun.c:925
#24 0x000000000043199a in sys_excepthook (self=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>) at ./Python/sysmodule.c:230
#25 0x00000000004aa1ac in _PyCFunction_FastCallDict (func_obj=func_obj@entry=0x7ffff7f61f78, args=args@entry=0x7ffff39176c0, nargs=nargs@entry=3, 
    kwargs=kwargs@entry=0x0) at Objects/methodobject.c:234
#26 0x0000000000451b68 in _PyObject_FastCallDict (func=0x7ffff7f61f78, args=args@entry=0x7ffff39176c0, nargs=nargs@entry=3, kwargs=kwargs@entry=0x0)
    at Objects/abstract.c:2313
#27 0x00000000004267f5 in PyErr_PrintEx (set_sys_last_vars=set_sys_last_vars@entry=1) at Python/pythonrun.c:669
#28 0x0000000000426a9a in PyErr_Print () at Python/pythonrun.c:532
#29 0x00007ffff4d54b78 in PrintError (msg=msg@entry=0x7ffff4d5bc7a "BUG: PySequence_Length")
    at /home/ns-sergeev/.pythons/src/Python-3.6.8/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.c:91
#30 0x00007ffff4d54e8e in _CallPythonObject (pArgs=0x7ffff3917a80, flags=4353, converters=0x0, callable=0x0, setfunc=0x0, 
    restype=0x7ffff4f631d0 <ffi_type_void>, mem=0x7ffff3917c20) at /home/ns-sergeev/.pythons/src/Python-3.6.8/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.c:149
#31 closure_fcn (cif=<optimized out>, resp=0x7ffff3917c20, args=0x7ffff3917a80, userdata=<optimized out>)
    at /home/ns-sergeev/.pythons/src/Python-3.6.8/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.c:296
#32 0x00007ffff4b42a6b in ffi_closure_unix64_inner (closure=0x7ffff7ff0cc0, rvalue=0x7ffff3917c20, reg_args=0x7ffff3917b70, 
    argp=0x7ffff3917c40 "\240\021\243") at ../src/x86/ffi64.c:667
#33 0x00007ffff4b42de4 in ffi_closure_unix64 () at ../src/x86/unix64.S:229
...
C-library frames are omitted
```

## Preliminary findings

It seems like arguments **converters** and **callable** of _CallPythonObject are not Ok (changed or corrupted by some reason).

frame 42 from normal backtrace. Normal values and callback called.

```
#42 0x00007ffff4d54d2c in _CallPythonObject (pArgs=<optimized out>, flags=257,
    converters=0x7ffff656a908, callable=0x7ffff4f9eea0, setfunc=0x0,
    restype=0x7ffff4f631d0 <ffi_type_void>, mem=0x7ffff3917c20)
```

frame 30 from error backtrace. Zero values and callback abandoned.

```
#30 0x00007ffff4d54e8e in _CallPythonObject (pArgs=0x7ffff3917a80, flags=4353, 
    converters=0x0, callable=0x0, setfunc=0x0,
    restype=0x7ffff4f631d0 <ffi_type_void>, mem=0x7ffff3917c20)
```

Can someone help with solving this issue or suggest a way to further dig and debug it?

Comment: Maybe include how you are calling the callable?

Comment: As in building the tuple/dictionary

Comment: @Neijwiert I have added more code to explain how the callback is called.

Comment: @Neijwiert I can't understand your second commentary. Cound you explain it?

Comment: Ignore my second comment, I assumed wrongly how you were invoking the Python side of things. I don't really have knowledge about ctypes and callbacks, but I do know how you could call a function from your c code. Is there any particular reason why you are not getting an attribute (your python function) from the c side?

Comment: @Neijwiert There must not be any reason because I have set callback at startup and just receiving events from C code. I'm not changing or updating the callback anyhow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192107/discussion-between-nick-and-neijwiert).

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `cfunction_pointer` rather than `py_callback_ptr = cfunction_pointer.value` to your library.

Minimal working example:

cside.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct DataStructure {
  int a;
} DataStructure;

typedef void (*callback)(char*, char*, DataStructure*, bool);

typedef void (*pcallback)(char*, char*, void*, bool);

int calc0(int, callback cb);

int calc1(int, pcallback cb);


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Note, that you don't need to define the signature where `DataStructure` is replaced by `void` anywhere in the C code. I have included it anyway to use a cast like in your question.

cside.cpp:

```
#include "cside.h"
#include "Python.h"

const char cstring1[] = "foo";
const char cstring2[] = "bar";

const bool bool_flag = false;

char* str1 = const_cast<char*>(&cstring1[0]);
char* str2 = const_cast<char*>(&cstring2[0]);

int calc0(int k, callback cb) {
  printf("Acquire GIL\r\n");
  PyGILState_STATE gstate;
  gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
  printf("Callback()\r\n");

  DataStructure s;

  // Execute callback with the signature known in C
  cb(str1, str2, &s, bool_flag);

  printf("Callback return\r\n");
  PyGILState_Release(gstate);
  printf("Release GIL\r\n");
  return k+2;
}

int calc1(int k, pcallback cb) {
  printf("Acquire GIL\r\n");
  PyGILState_STATE gstate;
  gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
  printf("Callback()\r\n");

  DataStructure s;

  // Cast to correct signature
  ((void (*)(char*, char*, DataStructure*, bool))cb)(
      str1, str2, &s, bool_flag);

  printf("Callback return\r\n");
  PyGILState_Release(gstate);
  printf("Release GIL\r\n");
  return k+2;
}
```

To compile:

```
g++ -I. -fPIC -shared -o libcside.so cside.cpp -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7
```

Test from within Python:

```
import ctypes

libc = ctypes.CDLL('libcside.so')

def callback(str1, str2, cdata, flag):
  print("PYTHON HANDLER")
  print(">>EXIT<<")

FuncType = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p,
                            ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_bool)

ctype_function_wrapper = FuncType(callback)
cfunction_pointer = ctypes.cast(ctype_function_wrapper, ctypes.c_void_p)
py_callback_ptr = cfunction_pointer.value

libc.calc0(2, cfunction_pointer)
libc.calc1(2, cfunction_pointer)

#libc.calc(2, py_callback_ptr) # segfaults
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! You said that you have segfaults when use py_callback_ptr. Do you always experience segfaults or just from time to time?

Comment: I can't use your example "as is" because SWIG wants me to pass to swig-wrapped-function parameters of exact types as they defined. So when I pass just cfunction_pointer to callback receiver function I see a message from SWIG "TypeError: in method 'CallbackSetter', argument 2 of type 'long'". I have tried to change callback parameter type to void* or to function declarartion (void (*)(char*, char*, DataStructure*, bool) but with no effect - SWIG always argues to "argument 2 doesn't match". while searching how to solve this issue I have found the "director" feature of SWIG. I'll try to use it.

Comment: With my setup, it always segfaults, but I can imagine you can have a situation, where it sometimes segfaults. I actually considered recommending you to use the `director` feature instead of `ctypes`. Another nice thing is to have SWIG generate an external runtime, you can use for converting objects to and from swig-wrapped objects.